# Enlarging RAID1 virtual drive online on LSI MegaRAID SAS 9240-8i without downtime?

Tags: raid, windows-server-2016, raid1, lsi, megaraid

I recently went out to a customer location and replaced + rebuilt a RAID1 drive group on their Lenovo TS440 server, going from 2 TB drives to 4 TB drives.

Question is - what's the best way to enlarge the virtual drive group? It's stuck at 2 TB and I can't find an option in LSI Storage Authority to expand it.

We need to minimize downtime as much as possible - we can afford a few reboots but not hours of downtime.

What's the best way to tackle this?

For additional information: The customer is on Windows Server 2016 Standard. Not a hypervised setup. Let me know if you need anything else.